# Pandas.Series get 10 values prior to a known date

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas.Series that looks something like this

```
data = 
                  '.INX'
    Date
    2019-01-29    2640.000000
    2019-01-30    2681.005561
    2019-01-31    2689.750205
    2019-02-01    2751.544352
    2019-02-04    2745.497311
    2019-02-05    2767.970645
    2019-02-06    2798.255994
    2019-02-07    2707.690765
    2019-02-08    2703.569149
    2019-02-11    2640.521470
    2019-02-12    2645.174583
    2019-02-13    2644.231926
    2019-02-14    2658.562312
    2019-02-15    2658.030814
    2019-02-19    2607.297839
    2019-02-20    2553.135199
    2019-02-21    2553.355821
    2019-02-22    2514.045036
    2019-02-25    2474.393290
    2019-02-26    2423.449722
```

I want to get 10 historical data points prior to '2019-02-20' but cannot figure out how.

I tried:

`data['2019-02-20':-10]`

and, probably not to my surprise, it didn't work. Can I mix index types in a smart way or do I have to get the index and find the correct dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like 'Date' is your index, so you can try convert to datetime if index is not yet datetime

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Then you can do:

```
df.loc[df.index < '2019-02-20'].tail(10)
```

or:

```
# extract 11 rows ending with the said date
# then taking top 10 rows
df.loc[:'2019-02-20'].tail(11).head(10)
```

**Note**: the second approach does not seem to work as expected  if the query date is not in the index.

Output:

```
                 '.INX'
Date                   
2019-02-05  2767.970645
2019-02-06  2798.255994
2019-02-07  2707.690765
2019-02-08  2703.569149
2019-02-11  2640.521470
2019-02-12  2645.174583
2019-02-13  2644.231926
2019-02-14  2658.562312
2019-02-15  2658.030814
2019-02-19  2607.297839
```

Comment: You just need `df.loc[:'2019-02-20'].tail(11)`

Comment: Easy when you know how. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for positions, so possible use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
p = data.index.get_loc('2019-02-20') + 1
df = data.iloc[p-10:p]
print (df)
                  .INX'
'Date                  
2019-02-06  2798.255994
2019-02-07  2707.690765
2019-02-08  2703.569149
2019-02-11  2640.521470
2019-02-12  2645.174583
2019-02-13  2644.231926
2019-02-14  2658.562312
2019-02-15  2658.030814
2019-02-19  2607.297839
2019-02-20  2553.135199
```

Comment: If OP wants 'prior to '2019-02-20' then the first line must be `p = data.index.get_loc('2019-02-20')` i.e. excluding that date

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the query date is not in the index.